# PHP regex, prevent numbers to contain dots and commas

Tags: php, regex, symfony

I'm looking for a regex to accept only numbers without dots and commas,

```
  8500 --> true
  75,001 --> false
  3.500 --> false
```

I'm trying this regex `/[^0-9,.]/`  but it doesn't work

Thank you for help

Comment: A regex: `^[0-9]+$`: `^` begin of line, `+` repeat factor 1..unlimited (here: at least one digit), `$` end of line,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For symfony assets :

@`Assert\Regex(pattern="/^[0-9]+$/",match=true,message="This field must not contain periods and commas")`

Answer (score 1):

Regex: `^\d+$`

Here is an explanation:
https://regex101.com/r/zjaCto/1

Here is php online example:
https://onlinephp.io/c/6673a